# How to perform T-Test in R including hypothesis

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I would like to do a t-test in R. Unfortunately, statistics has never been my best subject, so I'm wondering what the output of t.test in `R` exactly mean.
For testing purpose I performed a t-test on two normal distributed vectors with equal parameters. Since both distributions have the same parameters, the difference of the variance is 0:

```
t.test(rnorm(1e7,mean=0,sd=1),rnorm(1e7,mean=0,sd=1),mu=0)

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  rnorm(1e+07, mean = 0, sd = 1) and rnorm(1e+07, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
t = 0.5014, df = 2e+07, p-value = 0.6161
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.000652202  0.001100571 
sample estimates:
mean of x    mean of y 
2.836860e-04 5.950136e-05
```

This obviously gives me the t of the t-test. In order to do something useful with it, I have to formulate a hypothesis which should be tested.

1. How / where (in terms of `R`) do I formulate a hypothesis?
2. How do I know if my hypothesis is significant?

My idea was:

An interesting hypothesis on two data vectors might be: 
$$
H_{0}: \mu_{X}-\mu_{Y} = w
$$
vs.
$$
H_{1}: \mu_{X}-\mu_{Y} \neq w
$$
Where $\mu_{X}, \mu_{Y}$ are mean values of the underlying deviation of $X,Y$.
Since these might be different from the mean of the given data vectors, I have to use `t` in order to accept or refuse $H_{0}$ ($H_{1}$) (so far correct?).

Looking at wikipedia, $H_{0}$ is refused if $|t| > t(1-\frac{1}{2}\alpha, m+n-2)$ where $\alpha = 0.05$ (standard paramter of `t.test` in `R`) and $df=m+n-2$. In this case t(..,..) is some giant table where I can look up the corresponding value.

1. Where do I get this value in `R` and at which point did is specify $w$
   for $H_{0}, H_{1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to formulate the hypothesis before you do any tests. The
   hypothesis follows from your research question. In the case of the $t$-test, one possible two-sided hypothesis is the one you have given, i.e. that the difference between the two means equals some number. In most cases, $w=0$ and the $t$-test tests the null hypothesis that the two means are equal vs. that the two means are different. In the function `t.test` you can specify $w$ with the option `mu`. In the example that you provided, you've set $w=0$ so the null hypothesis is that the two means are equal. The output from `t.test` even states the alternative hypothesis: `alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0`. To specify a one-sided alternative hypothesis, use the `alternative` option of `t.test`. This may be `"two.sided"` for a two-sided alternative: the difference of means could be smaller *or* greater), `"greater"`: the difference between the means is greater than the value that you specified with `mu`, `"smaller"` for the one-sided hypothesis that the difference of the means is smaller.
2. The significance test is given by the output of `t.test` in `R`. It provides the $t$-value , the degrees of freedom and the corresponding $p$-value. In your case, it is not surprising that the $p$-value is not significant ($p>0.05$) because you generated both samples from a normal distribution with equal mean.
3. The output of `t.test` provides all necessary information but if you want to get the critical $t$-value manually, you can use the `qt` function in `R`. In your example this would be ($\alpha=0.05, df=2\cdot 10^{7}$): `qt(1-0.5*0.05, df=2e7)`. This gives the critical $t$-value of $1.96$. The $t$-value from your test is much lower and thus, you have not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis that the two means are equal. To get the $p$-value for a two-sided hypothesis in `R`, you could type: `2*pt(-abs(t),df=n-1)`. In your case $t=0.5014$ and thus: `2*pt(-abs(0.5014), df=2e7)` which yields $0.616$.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. This was very helpful! But one question remains: If I can only test, if the difference in means is equal to `w`, then I expect this test to fail every time. Depending on randomness, both means will never be exactly equal.

Comment: @user1228633 Yes, that's right, the means will never be *exactly* equal. But that is not the question since you cannot prove the null hypothesis anyway. All you can do is *reject* the null hypothesis with sufficient evidence. The $t$-test doesn't test if the means are equal, it tests if there is evidence that they are *not* equal.

Comment: @user1228633 The $p$-value answers the following question: If the null hypothesis were true (i.e. the means were really equal), what is the probability of receiving a $t$-value as least as extreme as the one that was observed. If this probability (i.e. the $p$-value) is very small, then we have evidence that the null hypothesis is unlikely. But the $p$-value is *not* the probability that the null hypothesis is true. See also [here](http://graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?what_is_a_p_value.htm).